# Alignment issue in Internet Explorer 8 with sidebar on some sites of a Wordpress multisite

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, alignment

I have a Wordpress multisite installation with these websites:

A portal: http://www.gprsoftware.nl which links to

- http://www.gpradvies.nl
- http://www.gprstedenbouw.nl
- http://www.gprspecials.nl
- http://www.gprgebouw.nl
- http://www.gpronderhoud.nl

The problem occurs on all pages of gprgebouw.nl and gpradvies.nl but not on the other domains. Here is a screenshot of the homepage of gprgebouw.nl

[image: gprgebouw.nl screenshot]

What happens:

1. the right sidebar slides under the content area
2. the bar-graph icon image is increased in size
3. grey borders of the sidebar are extended to the top of the content area

Especially point 3 makes me believe that somehow the content area is not closed properly, but I cannot find this in the HTML source.

The weirdest part is that this only happens on the mentioned websites and not on the others although they share all of the Javascript and plugins and most of the CSS (only some colours are different).

Of course all is fine in browsers like Firefox.

Any ideas what is causing this?
I'm using selectivzr and modernizr for IE lte 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://www.gprgebouw.nl you have a missing closing div tag here:

```
    <div class="aside-content">
        <div class="textwidget">
...
            <p><a href="http://www.gprprojecten.nl/Home/Details/19367" target="_blank"><img alt="Justus van Effen" src="http://software.gprgebouw.nl/start/images/thumb4476.jpg"> <span class="stars rating30"></span></a></p>
            <p><a href="http://www.gprprojecten.nl"onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-widget','http://www.gprprojecten.nl']);" target="_blank" class="a-landing">Bekijk meer projecten op www.gprprojecten.nl</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you, this was the HTML culprit, it took a while to find it in my code though. The problem was that in my functions.php file I add some html tags around my widgets, some of which to the title. But the menu does not display the title so there was a stray div there that I hadn't noticed. Firefox and other modern browsers are just much more forgiving then the old IE

Comment: will award bounty when stackoverflow will let me (6 hours from now)

Comment: how did you manage to find this actually? I tried it using firebug and checking out the html manually

Comment: I pulled the rendered page code into an editor and started tracing outward from various visible elements. Occasionally I pasted modified code into IE's developer tools Edit panel. Eventually the page popped into shape.

Comment: You haven't forgotten my loot, have you? :-)

Comment: I'm so, sorry, I did. Here you are!